# Play Framework 2.2.x and Angular: Redirect to mobile index page

Tags: angularjs, scala, httprequest, playframework-2.2

I'm working on an AngularJS project with the Play Framework 2.2. I'm supposed to develop a mobile version for the web application (not responsive, its part of a given uni project). For the desktop version I'm loading the index page with:

```
def index(any: String) = Assets.at(path = "/public", file = "app/html/index.html")
```

which works fine. Detection of the mobile browser works as well by examining the user agent in a Scala `Action`.

I changed the above code as follows to get the request header:

```
def index(any: String) = Action { implicit request: RequestHeader =>
  if(isMobile(request)) {
    // result for mobile version
  }
  else //result for desktop version
}
```

However, I don't know how to serve the different asset files as result type.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to serve different files from `Assets.at()` based on your `isMobile` test, but can't work out how to get the types to line up?

`Assets.at()` returns an `Action[AnyContent]` which is at its simplest a function from `Request[AnyContent]` to `Future[Result]`.

So knowing this, we just need a couple of tweaks to your `index` function and everything fits:

```
def index(any: String) = Action.async { request: Request[AnyContent] =>
  if(isMobile(request)) {
    Assets.at(path = "/public", file = "mobile.html").apply(request)
  } else {
    Assets.at(path = "/public", file = "desktop.html")(request)
  }
}
```

Explanations:

- The inner call returns a `Future[Result]` so we've become an `Action.async`
- `implicit` is not needed here so I dropped it
- An `Action` needs to be given a `Request` not a `RequestHeader` so I changed that
- I'm showing both `.apply(request)` and just `(request)` - they are exactly the same

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfectly! Im a newbie in scala so had a few troubles with it.